# this vs. currentValue of an iterator function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, iterator

Though distinct in their own way they often times serve a similar purpose. Simply put I was wondering which of the two is more performant than the other? In general is one more preferred than the other or is it really just a matter of personal preference?

```
$("div").each(function(index, element) {
  this.id
});
```

---

```
$("div").each(function(index, element) {
  element.id
});
```

Comment: It’s a matter of personal preference. If you care about micro-optimizing iteration, you probably shouldn’t be using jQuery.

Comment: Maybe using jQuery wasn't the best example for an *optimization* post XD.

Comment: Well, the advantage of the first piece of code is that you dont have to pass any arguments into the function. In the second one you have to pass both, since element is the second argument in there. But i wouldnt say that its a performance advantage :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`element` reference

```
$("div").each(function(index, element) {
  element.id
});
```

appear to be "fastest" . The margin is minimal. Last test tried at chromium 49 `element.id`:54,990 , `this.id`:54,885 . Results may vary based on browser, or browser version used. Or, as @RyanO'Hara succinctly points out

> generally that it doesn’t matter

jsperf http://jsperf.com/this-vs-currentvalue-of-an-iterator-function

Comment: Are the results from the test judged by an unseen time metric because their speed on the bar chart is showing both to be identical on my end.

Comment: @CarlEdwards The margin is minimal. Last test tried at chromium 49 `element.id`:54,990 , `this.id`:54,885

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for spotting out the difference.

Comment: Opposite results on Firefox. This isn’t true or useful.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara _"Opposite results on Firefox."_ Ok, did not try at firefox , here . _"This isn’t true or useful."_ ? _"The margin is minimal. Last test tried at chromium 49 element.id:54,990 , this.id:54,885"_ was and is true , here. Actually , your comment possibly makes Answer more useful, or at least jsperf ; as there are apparently different results returned based on browser , or browser version used. chrome 42 stable also gave different results, here. What were numbers returned by firefox ? Which version of firefox ?

Comment: Right now, your answer says that one method is fastest. That isn’t true. You should edit it to say what your comments do, or generally that it doesn’t matter.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara See updated post. Can share numbers returned by firefox ?